# RiverPod 2.0 Family Provider resetting state instead of updating

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm not sure why my provider is calling build each time I make a state update.

Essentially I'm calling `controller.createVoice` and that should then create a voice with an id and append it to `selectedIds` but for some reason, it's not. I'm suspecting it has to do with build being called and how I'm actually building things.

```dart
class _EditTopicScreenState extends ConsumerState<EditTopicScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller =
        ref.read(editTopicControllerProvider(topicId: widget.topicId).notifier);
    final state =
        ref.watch(editTopicControllerProvider(topicId: widget.topicId));
    final topicNameFieldController =
        TextEditingController(text: controller.name);
    return FlutterDataWidget<Topic?>(
        findRequest: ref.topics.findOne(widget.topicId, remote: false),
        child: (topic) {
          return Drawer(
                // ...
                ),
                body: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ...
                      VoiceCreatorV2(
                        onAdd: (name) => controller.createVoice(name),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Flexible(
                        child: VoicesSelectV2(
                          selectedVoiceIds: state.selectedIds,
                          onAdd: (voiceId) => controller.addVoice(voiceId),
                          onRemove: (voiceId) =>
                              controller.removeVoice(voiceId),
                        ),
                      ),
                      // ...
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ));
        });
  }
}
```

The Riverpod code is here, I'm using 2.0

```dart
@riverpod
class EditTopicController extends _$EditTopicController {
  @override
  EditTopicControllerState build({required String topicId}) {
    final voices = ref.voices.watchAll(remote: false).model;
    final activeVoices = voices?.where((v) => v.archivedAt == null).toList() ??
        []; // Used for sorting voices on load so the ones selected are first
    final topic = ref.topics.watchOne(topicId, remote: false).model;
    final selectedIds =
        topic?.voices.toList().map((e) => e.id!).toList() ?? [] as List<String>;

    final List<Voice> sortedVoices = [
      ...activeVoices.where((v) => selectedIds.contains(v.id)).toList(),
      ...activeVoices.where((v) => !selectedIds.contains(v.id)).toList()
    ]; // Used for sorting voices on load so the ones selected are first

    return EditTopicControllerState(
        name: topic?.name ?? '',
        selectedIds: selectedIds,
        sortedVoices: sortedVoices);
  }

  List<String> get selectedIds => state.selectedIds;
  String get name => state.name;
  void updateTopicName(String name) {
    state = state.copyWith(name: name);
  }

  void addVoice(String id) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedIds: [...state.selectedIds, id]);
  }

 //...

  void createVoice(String name) async {
    // used voice model to create voice
    final voice = await Voice.newVoice(
      name: name,
      color: HexColorParser().generateRandomHexColor(),
    ).save(remote: true);
    addVoice(voice.id!);
  }
//...
}
```

Frankly, I'm not sure if this is even the right way to handle something like this, and perhaps I'm missing a key concept to it, so if I am, let me know.

I hope this is all that's needed to get help!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This line was the culprit `final voices = ref.voices.watchAll(remote: false).model;`

Okay, so it turns out the issue was in the provider. I was watching all of the voices and because I'm watching them, when I create a new voice it completely rebuilds, due to it being watched, thus wiping out my state.